# Limitations placed on an Oracle Turing Machine for Relativized Theorems

Tags: first-order-logic, computability, turing-machines, oracles

Are there any limitations that need to be placed on an oracle in order to maintain that the classical computability results (like the Halting Problem and the non-collapse of the arithmetic hierarchy) still hold in the relativized world? My textbook says that oracles can be uncomputable but I wasn't sure if that means they still need to be definable somehow in first-order arithmetic.

Comment: The vast majority of computability-theoretic results relativize to arbitrary oracles without issue. In fact, it takes some work to find a sentence (for example) true in $\mathcal{R}$ but false in some $\mathcal{R}_a$, where $\mathcal{R}$ is the poset of c.e. degrees and $\mathcal{R}_a$ is the poset of degrees which are c.e. and above $a$. Certainly every result covered in a first-year graduate computability class would relativize.

Comment: (Sorry, "c.e. and above" should be "c.e. **in** and above" - $x$ is c.e. in and above $y$ iff $x\ge_Ty$ and $x\in\Sigma^0_1(y)$. This is usually abbreviated "c.e.a." or "CEA.")